# Find all items assigned to user in Azure DevOps organisation

Tags: azure-devops

I've just had a colleague leave my team who was involved in multiple Projects within our Azure DevOps organisation. I'd like to return a list of all items that are currently still assigned to him across all Projects (work items, pull requests, etc) so that I can reassign them. Is there a way to achieve this without having to run multiple queries in every different Project? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To find all work items assigned to the user in the organization, you can query across projects. Please see [Query across or within projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#query-across-or-within-projects) for more details.

However, for pull requests, this functionality is not currently available. Please try to use the filter to find active pull requests assigned to the user in each repository.
[image]